# How to convert flat/relational table to a key/value pair table in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, nosql

I have a table in which multiple rows have the same data except one column which has unique values in all the repeated rows.

Example:

```
userid, article_count, test_count, total_articles,total_tests,exam_id, exam_score

- 00016320-452b-11e6-9a4a-252aad95e99b,38,1,106,88,e9c196a1-4ae6-11e5-bc68-8620ffdeb79c,1
- 00016320-452b-11e6-9a4a-252aad95e99b,38,1,106,88,8223ff18-d538-11e5-80ff-b0086ec8f4cd,1
- 00016320-452b-11e6-9a4a-252aad95e99b,38,1,106,88,be2ac525-3909-11e6-a224-56a308185daf,1
```

I want to have a single row in the table for each user and treat exam_id, exam_score as key/value pair or record in BigQuery. 
I treated exam as a record having two sub fields: exam.exam_id and exam.score.

The output would be as follows:

```
userid, article_count, test_count, total_articles,total_tests,exam.exam_id, exam.score

- 00016320-452b-11e6-9a4a-252aad95e99b,38,1,106,88,e9c196a1-4ae6-11e5-bc68-8620ffdeb79c,1
                                                   8223ff18-d538-11e5-80ff-b0086ec8f4cd,1
                                                   be2ac525-3909-11e6-a224-56a308185daf,1
```

How to convert the table into the provided structure?

Answer (score 3):

How about using `array_agg()` with a struct?

```
select userid, article_count, test_count, total_articles, total_tests,    
       array_agg(struct(exam_id as 'exam_id', exam_score as 'exam_score')) as exams
from t
group by userid, article_count, test_count, total_articles, total_tests
```

Comment: array_agg() won't work in legacy sql format of BigQuery. Is a legacy sql hack possible?

Comment: @Prabhjot . . . Use standard SQL.